# How to scrape between specific tags using file_get_contents

Tags: php, web-scraping

I am using `file_get_contents` to scrape a html page. I would like the scrape to be between `<pre>` and `</pre>` tags only. Any ideas how to achieve this? The code is as follows:

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.atletiek.co.za/.....htm');
$tags = explode(' ', $html);

foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    // skip scripts
    if (strpos($tag, 'script') !== false) {
        continue;
    }

    // get text
    $text = strip_tags(' ' . $tag);

    // only if text present remember
    if (trim($text) != '') $texts[] = $text;
}
print_r($text);
```

Comment: [xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) can do it

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex if it's enough for you.

```
$s = 'test <pre>this is simple</pre> test <pre class="tricky">this is' . "\n" . 'tricky</pre> test';
if (preg_match_all('#<pre(?: [^>]*)?>(.*?)</pre>#msi', $s, $m)) {
    print_r($m[1]);
}
```

shows

```
Array
(
    [0] => this is simple
    [1] => this is
tricky
)
```

But please read this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/437763

May be you need XPath - http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding all the tags and attributes I wanted to exclude. I used `if (strpos($tag, 'script') !== false) {` for all the tags I did not want to load. It worked for me because there were only about 5 or six others.